# Get data from JSON file into EJS variable

Tags: json, ejs

I want to get data from this JSON file: https://restcountries.com/v3.1/name/Poland into a EJS variable 'userData' and show it on the screen. How can I get it done?

I tried:

```html
<%
const userData = require('https://restcountries.com/v3.1/name/Poland');
%>
<%= JSON.stringify(userData) %>
```

Comment: Where is the template rendered? Front-end? Back-end? static-site generator? You can't just require a url, you need to make an asynchronous request to fetch the data, assign it to a variable and only then render your template

Comment: On back-end. Yes, I'd like to do that using something like await/sync in plain JS.